# TCP/IP Socket connection send hex data using C# and JAVA

Tags: java, c#, sockets, tcp, serial-port

Hi I need to use TCP/IP or RS232 to communicate to an UHF RFID reader. I choose to use TCP/IP over RS232.

I need to execute hex command to the device as per below for send and receive data.

Host Command Data Packet Definition
[image]

Response Packet Definitaion

[image]

Some of the command definitaion
[image]

Example of command usage

[image]

This protocol is a communication specification for controlling the UHF RFID reader by its host computer via serial interface. Commands and responses consist of byte streams. The lengths of the streams are variable, and the packets are checked by checksum.

The physical interface is compatible with the RS – 232 specifications. 1start bit、8 data bits、1 stop bit、no even odd check. The baud rate can be set to 38400bps or 115200bps. The default baud rate is 115200bps.

How do I populate the hex data to send command and receive back data. I got problem on understanding the Data Packet Definition, at least if I knew how to structure the byte value will be easier for me. I'm open for any other approach as well. Thank you so much.

Comment: E.g. to send cmd_reset to address 0x12: `new byte[] { 0xA0, 0x03, 0x12, 0x70, 0x00 }`; the last byte (the check byte) still has to be calculated correctly.

Comment: Tqs for ur explanation will try and see how

Comment: how do we populate the address? Or just use a random non conflicting address?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to create your own class representing a message (here in C#):

```
public class CommandDataPacket
 {
 public byte Head
 {
  get
   {
   return 0xA0;
   }
  }

  public byte Length
  {
   get
    {
    return Data.Length + 3;
    }
   }

  public byte Address {get;set;}

  public byte Command {get;set;}

  public byte[] Data {get;set;} = new byte[0];

  public cyte Check
  {
   get
    {
     // did not find anything how to calculate the check Byte. You'll have to implement it
    }
   }

  public byte[] ToBytes()
   {
   List<byte> result = new List<byte>();
   result.Add(Head);
   result.Add(Length);
   result.Add(Address);
   result.Add(Command);
   result.AddRange(Data);
   result.Add(Check);
   return result.ToArray();
   }
 }
```

Please make sure that it really fulfills the specification in your question. I did not check it carefully, but I hope you'll get the idea how to implement something like that. Another class could be created for the Response Packet Definition.

You can use this class like following example:

```
CommandDataPacket msg = new CommandDataPacket
 {
 Address = 0x12,
 Command = 0x45,
 Data = new byte[] { 0x03, 0x05, 0x07 }
 };
byte[] rawMessage = msg.ToBytes();
```

You can use the TcpClient class to send this byte Array to another host.

Comment: let me try first

Comment: how do you get address value

Comment: There is a command with the description "set reader's address" with the code 0x73. I think with that one you can somehow set the address of every machine. But from what you posted, it's not clear to me what to put into the address byte when you initially send this command.

Comment: Actually the comprehensive command table code 0x73 belongs to cmd column, refer the sample table. Finding value for address column is the problem. CMD is the code we need to send to device as SET or GET for functionalities of the device. Hope this helped